# React: Unhandled error 500 when using API to get data from Prisma

Tags: reactjs, database, api, next.js, prisma

I am trying to get some data from my Prisma database by using an API, but I get errors.
This is my API:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case 'DELETE':
      const { id } = req.query
      const issue2 = await db.deleteUnique(id)
      res.status(204).end()
      break
      
    case 'GET':
      const issue = await db.findUnique(id)
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: issue })
      break
    default:
      res.status(405).end()
      break
  }
}
```

And this is my index.js file that sends a call to my API:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

  const Issue = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query
  
    const getIssue = async () => {
      // GET-request til /api/issues/[id].js
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/issues/${id}`)
    }
    
  
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Issue {id}</h1>
        <button onClick={getIssue}>Hent Id</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  export default Issue
```

The error I get is "Unhandled Runtime Error" after I click the button to get the ID, I have tried everything I can think of. Can anyone help?

```
createError
node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js (16:0)

settle
node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js (17:0)

XMLHttpRequest.onloadend
node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js (66:0)
```

Comment: Do you get more information about the runtime error? Row number, call stack etc?

Comment: Yes I can update the question @Viktor

Comment: Your Prisma query is also likely incorrect by the way. There is no `deleteUnique` operation in Prisma. You also have to mention the model name. Here is what the findUnique query _might_ look like:  ```await db.issue.findUnique({ where: {id} })```. I would suggest looking through the Prisma [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#read) a bit. Also, as others have mentioned, having a stack trace would help in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

there should be a try catch block of axios get request
and there is no connection between the get request and the switch block
(i meant you are not sending response.json() to the switch )

Comment: what do I need to add thats missing?

Comment: can you  put a link to your full project if possible ?

Comment: I want to but I collaborate with others so it would be difficult :s Is there something you need that I can post? I really appreciate your help